# .readline is struck thru and asking add @ SuppressWarnings "Deprecation"

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code that manages the files that are written and read. Eclipse strikes thru the .readLine() method. I am having a hard time understanding why and how to fix it. It must be some mental block because I have read the tutorial docs on Oracles website and that has not helped. Anyone able to but it into words that this newbie might be able to get?

```
import java.io.*;

public class DataBase {

public static String getExtension(File f) {
    String ext = null;
    String s = f.getName();
    int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

    if (i > 0 && i < s.length() - 1) {
        ext = s.substring(i + 1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return ext;
}

public static String readFile(String fileName) {
    String strData = "";
    if (!new java.io.File(fileName).exists()) {
        return strData;
    }

    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);


        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
        String line = "";


        while (dis.available() != 0) {


            line = dis.readLine();

            if (line.length() > 0) {
                if (line.contains("<br/>")) {

                    line = line.replaceAll("<br/>", " ");
                    String tempLine = "";
                    while((tempLine.trim().length()<1) && dis.available()!=0){
                        tempLine = dis.readLine();
                    }
                    line = line + tempLine;
                }
                line = line.replaceAll("\"", "");

                buff.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }


        fis.close();
        bis.close();
        dis.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return buff.toString();

}

public static boolean writeToFile(String fileName, String data, boolean append) {
    boolean isWrite = false;
    int dirIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf(getPathSeparator());
    if (dirIndex != -1) {
        String dir = fileName.substring(0, dirIndex) + getPathSeparator();
        java.io.File fDir = new java.io.File(dir);
        if (!fDir.exists()) {
            if (!fDir.mkdirs()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        java.io.FileOutputStream fout = new java.io.FileOutputStream(fileName, append);
        java.nio.channels.FileChannel fChannelWriter = fout.getChannel();
        byte[] bytesToWrite = data.getBytes();
        java.nio.ByteBuffer bBuffW = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(bytesToWrite);
        fChannelWriter.write(bBuffW);
        fChannelWriter.close();
        fout.close();
        isWrite = true;
    } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        isWrite = false;
    }
    return isWrite;
}

public static String getPathSeparator() {
    return java.io.File.separator;
}
}
```

Comment: It's struck through because the developer doesn't want you to use it, probably because it's an unmaintained method with a better alternative.

Comment: The docs for that method explain clearly why it's deprecated and what you should use instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine() - you must've been looking at the wrong docs.

Comment: Honestly, there shouldn't be any reason for you to use `DataInputStream` at all. Same for `available()` - generally when doing I/O you read until a read call fails (e.g. `readLine()` returns `null`) instead of checking for EOF manually.

Comment: Off topic aside: Your `.Close()` calls should be within a `finally` block especially if you are using them within a `try` block

Comment: Don't use StringBuffer unless you have to, try StringBuilder instead.

Comment: @JNYRanger Better yet, `try`-with-resources.

Comment: @chrylis Truth.  One step at a time for beginners though =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Deprecated** is a term meaning that an item is still around for backward compatibility, but that it has problems and you shouldn't use it for new code. Eclipse will let you know immediately if you use an element marked `@Deprecated`.

[The Javadocs for `DataInputStream.html#readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29) explain why it's deprecated (character-set issues) and what to do instead (use `BufferedReader` instead of `DataInputStream`). Always check the docs when you come across something deprecated; the developer usually explains why.